# How to use SQL to output latest info with multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have a "weather" table below with 3 cols:

```
 City Temperature Date
 New York    22 C 10/10/2005
 Seattle     21 C 10/10/2005
 New York    18 C 10/09/2005
 Seattle     20 C 10/09/2005
 Washington  17 C 10/09/2005
 New York    21 C 10/08/2005
 Washington  20 C 10/08/2005
```

I want to find out the latest info on the City and Temperature in 3 cols as well (see example):

```
 City Temperature Date
 New York    22 C 10/10/2005
 Seattle     21 C 10/10/2005
 Washington  17 C 10/09/2005
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Find the maximum (latest) date for each city in a sub-query then join on the date and city:

```
select weather.* 
  from weather
  inner join    
    (select city, max(date) from weather group by city) as latest
    on weather.date = latest.date
      and weather.city = latest.city
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods.  Personally, I think the following is the most expressive:

```
 SELECT * FROM weather w1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT * FROM weather w2 WHERE w2.city = w1.city AND w2.date > w1.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
select city, temparature, date 
from  weather t1
where date = (select max(date)
              from   weather t2
              where  t2.city=t1.city)
```

Option 2:

```
select t1.city, t1.temp, t1.date
from weather t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from weather t2
                  where t2.date > t1.date and t1.city=t2.city)
```

Comment: For option 2, @Larry is the winner! I didn't notice it before saving my answer :)